# Multiple variations in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column called: ['Names'], and say in this columns I have a list of names like such: jeff, Jeff, JEFF, bob, Bob, BOB. I want to be able to loop through this column and bring in all of the names. I just don't want to make multiple workbooks for the different variations of jeff and bob. I know they are the same person I want to put them in the same workbook. is their anyway to do this or would I have to map out all the different variations and then loop through the column?

Comment: A critical step in processing data is standardizing it. If any of the columns you are working on vary in formatting that you do not want, figure out a way to standardize it. For names this means setting all of them to lowercase/uppercase/camel case/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try first using

```
data['Names'] = data['Names'].str.lower()
```

This will convert all names to lower-case.

Comment: What if I had, Jeff inc auto, Jeff cons build, Jeff add trunc would their be a way to loop through and look at the first 4 letter and say okay that matches with jeff so we can add it to that workbook?

Comment: To split off the first word and make it lowercase, you could use ``data['Names'].str.split().str[0].str.lower()``. There are more details in Pandas' [working with text](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) docs.

Comment: Just a note to also possibly add [`data.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on the next line to remove the duplicates names.